# What is wrong/missing in this code for Optical Bloch Equations in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

for work I have to solve the Optical Bloch Equations for a 2-Level System and I appear to be really stuck on my code in Mathematica:

```
O=1;
g=1;
d=0;
sol3=NDSolve
[
{
x'[t]==g y[t] + I/2 (O* b[t] - O a[t]),
y'[t]==-g y[t]+ I/2 (O a[t]-O* b[t]),
a'[t]==-(g/2+I d) a[t] + I/2 =O* (y[t]-x[t]),
b'[t]==-(g/2-I d) b[t] + I/2 O* (x[t]-y[t]),
x[0]==1,
y[0]==0,
b[0]==0,
a[0]==0

},
{x,y},{t,0,100}
]
```

The Error I get is:  Syntax::tsntxi: "whole DE-System" is incomplete; more input is needed.

I would be very grateful if you could point out my error(s)

Thank you all :)

Comment: uhm 1 error may be related to the use of capital letters. Mathematica doesn't know what I is, if you mean the imaginary unit then the correct way to implement it is :ii:

Comment: also the third equation  has a "=" on the rhs

Comment: Guys thanks so much so far. sorry, this was my bad for writing the code here instead of directly copying it (which for some reason did not work out well). to clarify, O is an Omega, the "=" in the third equation does not exist in the code. I have changed the I to :ii: but it still yields the same error.

Comment: thanks to all of you. I managed to get it to work with using "Derivative[1]" instead of "  x'  ".  and @Bill an "Omega" is the greek letter for O.

Answer (score 0):

```
w = 1;
g = 1;
d = 0;
swl3 = NDSolve[{
        x'[t] == g y[t] + I/2 (w*b[t] - w a[t]),
        y'[t] == -g y[t] + I/2 (w a[t] - w*b[t]), 
        a'[t] == -(g/2 + I d) a[t] + I/2 w*(y[t] - x[t]), 
        b'[t] == -(g/2 - I d) b[t] + I/2 w*(x[t] - y[t]),
        x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, b[0] == 0, a[0] == 0},
     {x, y, a, b},
     {t, 0, 100}]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], a[t], b[t]} /. swl3], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

`a[t]` and `b[t]` are complex so they don't appear in the plot. You can plot the real and imaginary part separately.